# PIVOT multiple columns T-SQL with generated column names

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, pivot

--UPDATE 12/19 at bottom of original question--

I have a table

```
MYID  YEAR  Q1      Q2      Q3      Q4
----------------------------------------
UNIQ1   13  xxxx    xxxx    xxxx    xxxx
UNIQ1   12  xxxx    xxxx    xxxx    xxxx
UNIQ1   11  xxxx    xxxx    xxxx    xxxx
UNIQ2   13  xxxx    xxxx    xxxx    xxxx
UNIQ2   12  xxxx    xxxx    xxxx    xxxx
UNIQ2   11  xxxx    xxxx    xxxx    xxxx
```

I need the output to look like this

```
MYID    11_Q1   11_Q2   11_Q3   11_Q4   12_Q1   12_Q2   12_Q3   12_Q4   13_Q1   13_Q2   13_Q3   13_Q4
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
UNIQ1   xxxx    xxxx    xxxx    xxxx    xxxx    xxxx    xxxx    xxxx    xxxx    xxxx    xxxx    xxxx
UNIQ2   xxxx    xxxx    xxxx    xxxx    xxxx    xxxx    xxxx    xxxx    xxxx    xxxx    xxxx    xxxx
```

Two things need to happen:

1. I need to `pivot` (?) on the year and
2. then append the year to column name.

I've tried joins, unions, pivots. I am really at a loss. Thank you for any help.

I am using SQL Server 2008.

----update

The solution graciously provided by Becuzz works perfectly in the example above. However, there is a problem when the data does not have values for every year.

My table actually looks more like this:

```
MYID  YEAR  Q1      Q2      Q3      Q4
----------------------------------------
UNIQ1   13  xxxx    xxxx    xxxx    xxxx
UNIQ1   12  xxxx    xxxx    xxxx    xxxx
UNIQ1   11  xxxx    xxxx    xxxx    xxxx
UNIQ2   13  xxxx    xxxx    xxxx    xxxx
UNIQ2   12  xxxx    xxxx    xxxx    xxxx
UNIQ2   11  xxxx    xxxx    xxxx    xxxx
UNIQ3   11  xxxx    xxxx    xxxx    xxxx
```

What ends happening is that UNIQ3 or any value that does not exist in all years is thrown out. I demonstrate this on SQL fiddle.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/ffeab/1/0

If you change Becuzz's code down below to use "OUTER APPLY" instead of "CROSS APPLY", NULLS get inserted when there are missing years.

So the output would look like this:

```
MYID    11_Q1   11_Q2   11_Q3   11_Q4   12_Q1   12_Q2   12_Q3   12_Q4   13_Q1   13_Q2   13_Q3   13_Q4
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
UNIQ1   xxxx    xxxx    xxxx    xxxx    xxxx    xxxx    xxxx    xxxx    xxxx    xxxx    xxxx    xxxx
UNIQ2   xxxx    xxxx    xxxx    xxxx    xxxx    xxxx    xxxx    xxxx    xxxx    xxxx    xxxx    xxxx
UNIQ3   xxxx    xxxx    xxxx    xxxx    null    null    null    null    null    null    null    null
```

Comment: are the years fixed 11,12,13? other wise you need to do pivot using dynamic sql

Comment: No-- there are 11 years - currently 2002 through 2012  ... I put them as two digits because it looked a little cleaner -- The report will run each new year, but I can simply put as a requirement that the code needs to be updated annually.

Comment: have you tried denormalizing the quarters so you have `myID/Year/Qn` and then pivoting on `myID`?

Comment: Beth - interesting idea. I will look at the path of denormalizing as a possible method... I don't think it would help with the dynamic columns, but it might get me half-way there. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one of those times where this is a job for dynamic SQL.  You will have to adjust this to your database, but the following should do it

```
declare @years table
(
    [year] int
)
insert into @years values (11)
insert into @years values (12)
insert into @years values (13)

declare @quarters table
(
    [quarter] varchar(10)
)
insert into @quarters values ('q1')
insert into @quarters values ('q2')
insert into @quarters values ('q3')
insert into @quarters values ('q4')

declare @query varchar(max)
select @query = 'select * from (select distinct id from tempdata) d' + stuff((select ' cross apply (select ' + stuff((select ','  + q.[quarter] + ' as [' + cast(y.[year] as varchar(10)) + '_' + q.[quarter] + ']' from @quarters q for xml path('')), 1, 1, '') + ' from tempdata dx where dx.id = d.id and dx.[year] = ' + cast(y.[year] as varchar(10)) + ') d' + cast(y.[year] as varchar(10)) from @years y for xml path('')), 1, 0, '')
exec(@query)
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/38b9b/1)

Comment: Thank you. I will let you know if I am able to make it work. I will need to work on it today and modify it. In my real world application "MyID" is actually a multi-column identifier. I like your approach.

Comment: The actual query generated from this dynamic SQL becomes: 

`select * from (select distinct id from tempdata) d 
cross apply 
 (select q1 as [11_q1], q2 as [11_q2], q3 as [11_q3], q4 as [11_q4] from tempdata dx 
 where dx.id = d.id and dx.[year] = 11) d11 
cross apply 
 (select q1 as [12_q1], q2 as [12_q2], q3 as [12_q3],q4 as [12_q4] from tempdata dx 
 where dx.id = d.id and dx.[year] = 12) d12 
cross apply 
 (select q1 as [13_q1], q2 as [13_q2], q3 as [13_q3], q4 as [13_q4] from tempdata dx 
 where dx.id = d.id and dx.[year] = 13) d13`

Comment: It works perfectly, the only significant adjustment I had was to change the construction of the @years table. To make it persist from year to year, I dynamically construct it as follows: 

`declare @years table
(
    [year] int
)
insert @years select distinct(year) from tempdata`

Comment: What I like most about your solution is that you are using code to create code to execute it.

Comment: This is a tiny little change from the answer proposed by Becuzz

Instead of using "cross apply", use "outer apply which allows for data with missing years.